# How to hold a for loop waiting for a process to end?

Tags: python

I wrote a short Python 3 script to run a batch file (`Ctemp.cmd`) multiple times. The script is this:

```
for i in range (START,STOP+1,STEP):
    os.startfile('Ctemp.cmd')
```

The above code runs the file at (almost) the same time. However, I would like it to wait untill the batch file has completed running and then run it again.

Comment: If you want to call external commands and keep control over it, you should look into ‘subprocess’

Comment: Are you asking how to run the batch files sequentially (i.e. one at a time)? Or are you asking how to block in the python script until every batch file is done?

Comment: one at the time...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Just change your code like below:-

```
for i in range (START,STOP+1,STEP):
    os.system("Ctemp.cmd")
```

Better always use a full path for your cmd file. If still you have issue change the `Ctemp.cmd` file to `Ctemp.bat` that may fix your issue.

Answer (score 1):

**Answer for Python 3.6.3:**

As [per documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/subprocess.html) :

> Run the `subprocess` module with the `.run` method. As so:
>
> `subprocess.run(args, *, stdin=None, input=None, stdout=None,
>   stderr=None, shell=False, cwd=None, timeout=None, check=False,
>   encoding=None, errors=None)`
>
> Run the command described by args. Wait for command to complete, then
>   return a `CompletedProcess` instance.

**This answer is for people running Python 2.7:**

You can use the 'subprocess' module and the `.check_call` method.

As per [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html):

> `subprocess.check_call(args, *, stdin=None, stdout=None, stderr=None, shell=False)`
>
> Run command with arguments. Wait for command to complete. If the
>   return code was zero then return, otherwise raise
>   `CalledProcessError`. The `CalledProcessError` object will have the
>   return code in the `returncode` attribute.

As Raf mentioned in the comments:

If you aren't concerned with catching errors you could just run the `.call` method instead.

> `subprocess.call(args, *, stdin=None, stdout=None, stderr=None,
>   shell=False)`
>
> Run the command described by args. Wait for command to complete, then
>   return the `returncode` attribute.

Comment: If you don’t bother about catching errors, just ‘.call(...)’ does the job.